# MySQL: Optimize query with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, distinct

In my Java application I have found a small performance issue, which is caused by such simple query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a 
   FROM table 
  WHERE checked = 0 
  LIMIT 10000
```

I have index on the `checked` column.

In the beginning, the query is very fast (i.e. where almost all rows have `checked` = 0). But as I mark more and more rows as checked, the query becomes greatly inefficient (up to several minutes).

How can I improve the performance of this query ? Should I add a complex index

- a, checked

or rather

- checked, a?

My table has a lot of millions of rows, that is why I do not want to test it manually and hope to have lucky guess.

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN the_query` ?

Comment: What are the values in the `checked` column?  Because there's no value in having the index if the values are only 0 or 1.  Or if zero makes up more than 50% of the `checked` column values.

Comment: that I have to go through all rows

Comment: @OMG Ponies interesting point! indeed it is boolean, can you provide any resources that explains why there is no point in having index? At the beginning 0 is in 100% rows, but at the end of the day it will become 0%

Comment: The concept is called "low cardinality" - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a completely different solution which would do the trick. I will simple create a new table with all possible unique "a" values. This will allow me to avoid DISTINCT

Comment: This will break normalisation and should generally be only the last fallback solution.

Comment: You're not avoiding the DISTINCT if you're using it to populate this temp table... ;)

Comment: @inflagranti it will not, if you treat "a" column as a ID (and indeed it as a ID)

Comment: @OMG Ponies I will use group by ! ;-) 1:0 for me :)

Comment: @inflagranti it can be a very well normalized solution. It depends on what the `a` is.

Comment: There's no performance difference between `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`; `GROUP BY` is just more flexible (aggregates).  Still think you're clever?

Comment: @mkk `group by` and `distinct` technically is the same thing.

Comment: i know it is more or less the same, i was just joking :)

Comment: About normalization: It will not break normalization rules on the table level, but if you look a the bigger picture of normalization, you do want to avoid duplicating data, as duplicated data is harder to maintain. And this clearly duplicates data and will force updates to happen in two places.

Comment: you are wrong. I will move my "a" and "checked" into another table, and I will have to update only it. I will leave my previous table in peace. Actually it is completely another way around - I WILL normalize my structure ;) checked depends on "a" and nothing else!

Comment: @mkk you'll only be partially normalising if you limit the output to 10,000 records out of millions.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an index on `checked, a`. This means that the value you're returning has already been found in the index and there's no need to re-access the table to find it. Secondly if you're doing lot's of individual updates of the table there's a good chance both the table and the index have become fragmented on the disc. Rebuilding (compacting) a table and index can significantly increase performance.

You can also use the query rewritten as (just in case the optimizer does not understand that it's equivalent):

```
  SELECT a 
    FROM table 
   WHERE checked = 0 
GROUP BY a
   LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Yeah, but `checked` value is not selective at all, so I believe it will not give the expected performance. Mathematically the best possible index is `a, checked`, but I don't think MySQL is able to use such index. So I think the best index should be simple `a`.

Comment: @Karolis: Index on `(checked,a)` can be used here. See `GROUP BY optimization` (last paragraph: 7.3.1.12.2. **Tight Index Scan**)

Comment: @ypercube, Ben, `(a, checked)` seems better. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295748/mysql-optimize-query-with-distinct/7295757#7295757 and the comments under it

Comment: @Ben see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html (GROUP BY optimization apply to DISTINCT), http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html (MySQL know how to use indexes for optimizing group by) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295748/mysql-optimize-query-with-distinct/7295757#7295757) ;)

Comment: @arnaud576875: Have you checked the "Tight Index Scan" paragraph? OP says that at the end of the day, there are more and more records with `checked = 1`. This means that selectivity is changing. An index on `a` or `(a,checked)` will be slower in that case (when there are few records with `checked=0`)

Comment: @ypercube Sure it can use the index `(checked,a)`, but I was not sure about `(a,checked)` which mathematically is better.

Comment: @Karolis: Imagine a table with 1M records where all `a` are different and there is only one record with `checked=0`. Which index do you think will be better?

Comment: @ypercube "Tight Index Scan" would be better than "Loose index scan" if there was very few `checked=0`, but given OP's query performances with an index on `checked`, I doubt that it's the case.

Comment: @arnaud576875: Yes, you are right, the problem may not be the index only. I'd like to know the memory settings and whether the index could be fully loaded into the RAM (and if that improves performance). Or if analyzing the table helps (as someone suggested).

Comment: @ypercube In my opinion if absolutely all (not almost all) rows have `checked=0` then _in theory_ there should be almost no difference between `(checked, a)` and `(a, checked)` because the index size should be very similar.

Comment: @ypercube Oh, sorry. I read your comment wrong. You mean only one record `checked=0` (not all). But as _arnaud576875_ said this is not the case :)

Comment: OP says otherwise: *"In the beginning, the query is very fast (i.e. where almost all rows have checked = 0). But as I mark more and more rows as checked, the query becomes greatly inefficient (up to several minutes). "*

Comment: @ypercube Ok, it was not clear how much rows become checked. But keeping in mind that the query becomes slow, it may mean that you are right about its data. So `(checked,a)` should do the job in this case. But also I noticed OP's comment: _At the beginning 0 is in 100% rows, but at the end of the day it will become 0%_. So if these updates are done every day, then the query needs several indexes for different situations. But for this case InnoDb engine is needed (instead of MyISAM) in order to have index distribution information always up to date. // anyway +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a compound index on the DISTINCT column (`a` in this case). MySQL is able to use this index for the `DISTINCT`.

MySQL may also take profit of a compound index on `(a, checked)` (**the order matters**, the DISTINCT column has to be at the start of the index). Try both and compare the results with your data and your queries.

(After adding this index you should see `Using index for group-by` in the `EXPLAIN` output.)

See **[GROUP BY optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)** on the manual. (A `DISTINCT` is very similar to a `GROUP BY`.)

> The most efficient way to process GROUP BY is when an index is used to directly retrieve the grouping columns. With this access method, MySQL uses the property of some index types that the keys are ordered (for example, BTREE). This property enables use of lookup groups in an index without having to consider all keys in the index that satisfy all WHERE conditions.>

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL will use this to improve the performance of distinct?

Comment: Yes, DISTINCT's are GROUP BY's, and MySQL knows how to use indexes for GROUP BY's.

Comment: `DISTINCT` returns unique sets; `GROUP BY` groups based on the designated columns.  They perform the same, and on all but edge cases will they return identical result sets.

Comment: I would change the compound index to checked first, THEN a... since the person wants all "checked" first, then distinct "a" values within it.

Comment: I will try to add this index and check if it will be used. If this will be true, I will accept this answer

Comment: @DRapp No, MySQL wouldn't be able to use the index for the group by. And `checked` is not much selective, so an index on this column is close to useless if there are many *checked* rows. From the manual: `[this optimization is possible if] The GROUP BY names only columns that form a leftmost prefix of the index and no other columns`

Answer (score 1):

> My table has a lot of millions of rows <...> where almost all rows have
>   checked=0

In this case it seems that the best index would be a simple `(a)`.

**UPDATE:**

It was not clear how many rows get checked. From your comment bellow the question:

> At the beginning 0 is in 100% rows, but at the end of the day it will
>   become 0%

This changes everything. So @Ben has the correct answer.

Comment: @mkk Does your query use this index? By the way, what is the table type? (innodb or myisam)

Comment: @mkk So, try to force the index on `a` in your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: did not work, possible keys are NULL and still all rows have to be crawled

Comment: @mkk the information about possible keys are not always true. The main thing is the key the query actually uses. The query should be able to use index `a` for such a simple query. Are you sure you do everything right?

Comment: @mkk Also it's likely that the query can work without index hints, but then you may need to update key distribution information for your table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: i double checked and of course you were right i did not do everything right :) when I typed the correct name of my index ( : ) ) explain said that it is able to use it, though still all rows must be crawled. I guess I will stop playing around with indexes and I will normalize my table - thanks for the input though!

Comment: If allmost all rows have thesame value then the cardinality of the row is low and mysql will not use an index because using an index on low cardinality column is pointless

Comment: @Johan He didn't say that `a` have the same value. Or I missed something? :)

Comment: there are millions of various values of "a", I wouldn't describe it as "low cardinality column"

Comment: @mkk my bad i thought i read that, anyway if 40%+ of a column = 0 and you're selecting a=0 then using an index is usually pointless and if mysql knows this info (it keeps stats on columns) it will not select an index that was my point

Answer (score 0):

You don't state it, but are you updating the index regularly?  As changes occur to the underlying data, the index becomes less and less accurate and processing gets worse and worse.   If you have an index on checked, and checked is being updated over time, you need to make sure your index is updated accordingly on a regular basis.

Comment: how can I ensure that the index will be updated? That might be the actually the core reason for my issue! I thought it will be updated automagically, but most probably i am wrong. I do about 60.000 updates every 1/2/3.. minutes using UPDATE table set checked=1 (time depenends on the stage of my application, because it takes me more and more time to find proper rows to process).

Comment: @Thyamine Doesn't MySQL always keep its indexes up to date?

Comment: @arnaud on innodb yes on myisam sometimes not